# explain about the multiclass SVM using one-vs-all to choose the output

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

Here is the content I read on http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/multiclass-svms-1.html. 
This say that: "In particular, the most common technique in practice has been to build classifier one-versus-rest classifiers (commonly referred to as "one-versus-all" or OVA classification), and to choose the class which classifies the test datum with greatest margin".
I really don't understand what that means? What is the test datum here? I only understand that one-versus-rest that: For each particular class, they will create 1 hyperplane between that class and the rest. Then when a new record comming to the model to get classified to which class it should be belong to. So How to choose the right class for new record in this case?
Let me show what I think about the quotes: I think that there are N classes ~ N classifiers (hyperplane) ~ N margins. The new record, which is need to classified, is belong to the class has greatest margin (among N margins) AND that record is positive to that class (mean that record is not on the rest).
Did I understand right?
Please help me with good explain, use less academy words because my English is not good at academy environment, I can misunderstand anytime because of bad explain.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVMs will yield a distance from the hyperplane.

You predict the class, where this distance is the largest (but worst case, all may be negative!), as you assume this classifier has the highest confidence.